# Is it normal that Mass Effect 3 automatically opens Priority: Cerberus Headquarter after the ending credits scene?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I have finished Mass Effect 3, and I have got the perfect ending where:

> 1. Shepard lives
>  2. The Normandy is almost fine and is flying again
>  3. All the crew members are alive

Now, after the ending credits scene, the game automatically opened just before Priority: Cerberus Headquarter. Can anyone confirm if that is normal? I thought that I would be returned to the main menu.

What I expected according to what I read online is:

> This ending is left opened on purpose. However, after Liara 'Shepard's romance' refused to place Shepard's name on the wall and looked to the deep, and after the Normandy launches, and after the scene where Shepard took a breath, and after some speeches from Admiral Hacket, and other scenes. Then come the credits and at last a message from BioWare Mass Effect team asking for a feedback. **After all of that**, the normal behavior is the game should take me to the main menu.

Comment: Just loaded my save game and did the credits. After final cutscenes, returned to main menu.

Comment: @ShawnGordon so, what the hell is going on with my saves? and why after the credits I am not returning to the main menu? This might make a program with my character if there is a DLC or for another part of the game if any :(

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this problem, as in, does this happen every time to you?

Comment: I had a copy from the last autosave, that autosave is just before the Crucible.
For your question, yes it happened again...

Comment: What platform are you having this issue (i.e. PS3, XB, PC, etc.)

Comment: PC with Windows 10

Comment: That would explain a difference in outcome. I tested on PS3, so I wouldn't be able to recreate the issue for you. However, I may be able to dig up some reference resource for you. Hold on a few.

Comment: You by chance didn't import an ME2 save when you started ME3, did you?

Comment: No, I successfully imported my ME2 profile, and everything went fine during all the game play.

Comment: What DLC do you have?

Comment: I have all the DLCs :) And I have successfully played them all.

Comment: Then I'm stumped - the Leviathan DLC was supposed to fix savegame issues that arise from ME2 import ME3 and address a few romance acknowledgement bugs. Anything I've read in the EA, Bioware, Fandom, Wikia, and offshoot sites have no instances of people with your problem. Unfortunately I don't know how better to help you. I'm sorry

Comment: :( So, what I am now supposed to do? I only have an autosave that direct me to the Crucible directly. and I have a New Plus Saved Game too file.
Thank you for your help really.

Comment: I'm curious about your choice: IIRC, the only ending when Shepheard lives is the one where you destroy the Reapers and all AI life - which includes two Normandy crew members: EDI and Legion.

Answer (score 1):

Not normal.

After loading my game, finishing, and letting credits roll I was returned to main menu.

Considering you've done nothing that would prompt the game to loop you back to a save-state after credits, it appears you've found an odd glitch.

Comment: No, I didn't do anything at all, that is weird.

Comment: What was the last saved game when you hit load game?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question.

Comment: I meant, if you opened the game right now and loaded the last saved game, what mission would it be? The one before the Crucible? O before the illusive man?

Comment: Off the top of my head, right before I have to run into the Crucible.

Answer (score 1):

Playing on PS3, I've always been returned to the Normandy before the assault on Cronos Station, after finishing ME3. Never to the title screen. That's the point of No Return™ so it makes sense. It lets you go back and play DLCs, etc., without having to find an old save you may not even have.